# Could not reach HERE server during a Route query at runtime

Tags: android, dns, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

On April 14, 2020, Our Android app suddenly became unable to obtain routes from HERE api. The network timed out with messages that we could not reach `v151-91-30-0.route.hybrid.api.here.com`

Our app could authenticate to HERE to query road data but requests for routes failed with network connection timeout.

Solution: **Factory resetting the tablet got us past the problem.**

That solution is not really tolerable, especially if it happens again.

Tablets with the issue:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab S3, Model number: SM-T820
- Android 9, kernel: 3.18.115-16530048
- Software version: T820XXU3CSH9/T820XAR3CSH2/ with security patch level: August 1, 2019

Our new Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 tablets did not have the problem.

Things that didn't work:

1. Updating software on tablet - there were no updates.
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling our app.
3. Updating to latest HERE Android SDK (we updated from 3.10 to 3.15).
4. Resetting Android network settings.

Our Application:

- Developing on macOS Mojave, version 10.14.6
- Android minSdkVersion 23, targetSdkVersion 28
- Kotlin version 1.3.72
- Android Studio: 3.6.3
- HERE Android SDK: 3.15

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround which was to manually delete the HERE cache directory on the tablet using the File application. The cache directory is set when you call: MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot)

This is not an ideal solution. Still looking for a way to detect and resolve this problem at runtime without manually deleting a hidden cache directory.